# tensorflow.data batching method not batching lines of text from dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow

I was following the tensorflow tutorial by Stanford [tensorflow link](https://cs230-stanford.github.io/tensorflow-input-data.html) and I've hit a brick wall.

I'm reading data from a text file that has the following lines:

```
I use Tensorflow
You use PyTorch
Tensorflow is better
By a lot
```

when using a oneshot iterator, the batch method works fine

```
# Reading the file with tf.data
import tensorflow as tf

dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset("file.txt")

iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator() # iter can loop through data once
next_element = iterator.get_next() 


#---TRANSFORMING DATA---

# create batches 
batch_size = 2
dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size) 

# prefetching data (transfer from main storage to temp for faster loader)
dataset = dataset.prefetch(1)

iterator = dataset.make_one_shot_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()
with tf.Session() as sess:
    for _ in range(4//batch_size):
        print(sess.run(next_element))
```

This returns as expected (note that comments aren't part of output):

```
[b'I use Tensorflow' b'You use PyTorch'] # first batch
[b'Tensorflow is better' b'By a lot'] # second batch
```

However when I do a similar exercise with an initializable iterator...

```
# Using initializable iterators
import tensorflow as tf

dataset = tf.data.TextLineDataset("file.txt")
iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
next_element = iterator.get_next()
init_op = iterator.initializer # this allows you to reset iterator --> you can iterate multiple times (epochs)

epochs = 2
batch_size = 2
num_examples = 4

# This code block doesn't seem to work


dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size) # doesn't batch up lines


dataset = dataset.prefetch(1)
with tf.Session() as sess:
    # Initialize the iterator
    for i in range(epochs):
        sess.run(init_op)
        for _ in range(num_examples//batch_size): # loops through all batches
            print(sess.run(next_element))
        print("\n")
```

...I get this result:

```
# first epoch
b'I use Tensorflow' #??
b'You use PyTorch'

# second epoch
b'I use Tensorflow'
b'You use PyTorch'
```

What I expected:

```
# First epoch
[b'I use Tensorflow' b'You use PyTorch'] # first batch
[b'Tensorflow is better' b'By a lot'] # second batch

# Second epoch
[b'I use Tensorflow' b'You use PyTorch'] # first batch
[b'Tensorflow is better' b'By a lot'] # second batch
```

Could someone help me figure out what I'm doing wrong?  I've checked the documentation for batch() and everything looks like it checks out.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Move the `dataset.batch(batch_size)` line to be *before* creating the creation of the iterator.

Comment: thank you so much.  I would also really appreciate it if you could elaborate why this must be the case (this way I don't forget)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe, because you call `sess.run(init_op)` on every epoch? Call it once before the loop.

Comment: i made that change, didn't change the result